# Find the biggest file in a directory. Perl

Tags: perl

The program lists all files in a directory, their size, type and owner. In case file is a directory, owner is the owner of the biggest file in that directory (that's the problem).

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;

use feature 'say';
use File::Find;

my $dir = shift || die "Provide a directory name";
my @file;
my @owner;
my @size;
my @type;   
my $i = 0;

while( glob("$dir/*") )
{
    $file[$i] = $_;
        find(sub { $size[$i] += -s if -f }, $_);
    if( -d $file[$i] )
    {
        $type[$i] = "d";
        $owner[$i] = getpwuid((stat($_))[4]);
    }
    elsif ( -l $file[$i] )
    {
        $type[$i] = "l";  
            $owner[$i] = getpwuid((stat($_))[4]);
    }
    else 
    {
        $type[$i] = "f";
            $owner[$i] = getpwuid((stat($_))[4]);
    }
    print "$file[$i]:$owner[$i]:$type[$i]:$size[$i]\n";
    $i++;

}
```

At this point in code

```
if( -d $file[$i] )
        {
            $type[$i] = "d";
            $owner[$i] = getpwuid((stat($_))[4]);
        }
```

i have to find the biggest file in this directory. I figured, that i should use `find` function, but not sure on how to do it.

Comment: Following your design above, why not just get the current size (using `(stat($_))[7]`) and then use a new hash to store the biggest filename (key) and filesize (value).  If each pass thru the WHILE shows the current size is bigger, replace the item in the hash.  Or even just use simple $BIGGEST_FILENAME and $BIGGEST_FILESIZE vars.

Comment: @jimtut i have to search the whole subtree

Comment: I understand. But it’s only the biggest file in the entire subtree, right? Store the name of the biggest file and it’s file size in some thing like a hash or two separate variables. Every time you find a file whose size is bigger, replace the contents of that hash or variables. When you are done with the while loop, print out the name and size of the item in that hash or variables. (If you initialize the saved file size as zero, then the first file that you process will be bigger than that and will automatically be the first item saved, but will get over written when you find bigger files.)

Comment: This needs to be recursive, correct?  (It isn't, as it stands.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please investigate the following code piece for compliance with your task.

The code uses recursion for directories, core component is [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob) function.

The result of directory lookup is returned as hash reference. Fill free to utilize this reference as your heart desire.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $dir = shift || die "Provide directory";

my $result = dir_lookup($dir);

say Dumper($result);

exit 0;

sub dir_lookup {
    my $dir = shift;

    my($record,$max);
    my @items = glob("$dir/*");

    $max = 0;

    for my $name ( @items ) {
        my $data;
        $data->{name}  = $name;
        $data->{size}  = -s $name;
        $data->{owner} = getpwuid((stat($name))[4]);
        $data->{type}  = 'link' if -l $name;
        $data->{type}  = 'file' if -f $name;
        $data->{type}  = 'dir'  if -d $name;
        if( $data->{size} > $max and -f $name ) {
            $max = $data->{size};
            $record->{file} = $data;
        }
        if( $data->{type} eq 'dir' ) {
            my $r = dir_lookup($data->{name});
            $data->{file}  = $r->{file};
            $data->{owner} = $r->{file}{owner};
        }
        push @{$record->{items}}, $data;
    }

    return $records;
}
```